# How to write ${$var} with $_REQUEST[]

Tags: php, request

The following example works fine:

```
$name = 'MrSmith';
$var  = 'name';
echo ${$var};
```

But when submitted I need to use `$_REQUEST` and I can not figure out how to write it. This did not work:

```
$_REQUEST[${$var}]
```

What is the correct syntax for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you just want:

```
$_REQUEST[$var];
```

This will give you the value of `$_REQUEST['name']` if `$var` = 'name'

Also for your original example, this also works:

```
echo $$var;
```

I suggest reading the section on [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

Comment: You are right. It worked perfect! Thank you for the help and link.

Comment: @user1771176 Glad it worked for you. Please don't forget to mark this as the accepted answer :)

Answer (score 0):

`$$var` is a variable variable. If `$var` is equal to 'name' as described in your question it will look for the variable `$name`. `$name` is undefined. Consider the following:

```
$var = 'name';
$_REQUEST['name'] = 'test';

$_REQUEST[$$var]; // is the same as...
$_REQUEST[$name]; // which is the same as...
$_REQUEST[NULL]; // since $name is not set.

echo $_REQUEST[$var]; // prints 'test' because $var evaluates to 'name'.
```